# Storing List<T> in Couchbase/Memcached in addition to each T?

Tags: c#, memcached, couchbase, enyim, enyim.caching

I'm using Couchbase/Memcached to pre-compute a bunch of search results and keep them in memory to serve to clients, instead of them doing the searches themselves.

A set of search results is a List. If however a customer clicks into a given search result I'll need to pull up details on that T itself. Can I query Couchbase for just a given element of a List, or is there some other cleverer way I should be approaching this?

I saw this question ([Couchbase: is it better to retrieve a list object or each object individually?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10077131/couchbase-is-it-better-to-retrieve-a-list-object-or-each-object-individually)) but it doesn't really seem to fit what I'm after...

Comment: It is hard to answer questions like this without more details. Would it be possible to get an example of the documents you will be storing?